# declare interface in typescript from module

Tags: typescript, vue.js

How do I declare a type so my `ts` file compile?

I'm using vue and what I'm trying to do is to create a mixing: I'm using:

```
import Vue, {ComponentOptions, VueConstructor} from 'vue';

let mixin : ComponentOptions<Vue> = {
  computed: {
    logger() : Logger {
      console.log(this.$options._componentTag);
    }
  },
};
```

`ComputedOptions` has the definition [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/dev/types/options.d.ts#L166-L170). But this code fails to compile with

> this.$options._componentTag: with exception ts2339 property
>   _componentTag doesn't exist on type ComputedOption

I also tried to declare this type but no success:

```
declare module 'vue' {
  interface ComputedOptions<T> {
    _componentTag?: string;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `vue-property-decorator` over at [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-property-decorator). Creation of mixins with this library is very simple:

```
import { Component, Vue } from "vue-property-decorator";

@Component
export default class BaseMixin extends Vue {
  check = false;

  someMethod() {
    this.check = true;
  }
}
```

And then you can use it in components:

```
import { Component, Mixins } from "vue-property-decorator";
import BaseMixin from "@/mixins/BaseMixin";

@Component
export default class MyComponent extends Mixins(BaseMixin) {
   mounted() {
     this.someMethod(); // someMethod is visible here
   }
}
```

### ComponentOptions

But, if you need to extend `ComponentOptions` interface, maybe this helps you:
(`my_vue.d.ts`)

```
import Vue from 'vue';

declare module 'vue/types/options' {
    interface ComponentOptions<V extends Vue> {
        _componentTag?: string;
    }
}
```

You can use them in components and mixins:
(`MyMixin.ts`)

```
import { Component, Vue } from "vue-property-decorator";

@Component
export default class MyMixin extends Vue 
{
    check() {
        return this.$options._componentTag;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to use it with global mixins? I use `Vue.mixin(BaseMixin)` and I receive a long [exception](https://gist.github.com/akoidan/7ffd1953d09ba7c68cdbef29bc1ace51). I see [resolved issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component/issues/83), but seems it doesn't work. Im still getting an [error](https://snag.gy/TJYBXt.jpg) with declaring module in your way. I'm using [gts](https://github.com/google/gts)

Comment: I'm affraid that is imposible with `vue-property-decorator`. If you need declare some method that you will use in all components, better use vue [plugins](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html) maybe?

Comment: Do you know why ts refuses to compile? I can create a github example or snippet if you can't reproduce.

Comment: I suppose that `vue-property-decorator`'s mixin has another type that vue expected. For creating global mixins you can try [vue-typed](https://vue-typed.github.io/vue-typed/usage/mixins/global.html)

Comment: I mean why `declare module` doesn't work. So if some module exports a module like vue does (this can be something else but vue) and I can't override interface of inner class with `declare`. This is not related to vue in anyway, only to typescript itself.

Comment: I update answer with code, that compiled successfully with vue cli.

Comment: It doesn't, we probably use different tsconfig settings. I created the example: https://github.com/akoidan/55392496 Could you please check it out? I tried declaring type above `main.ts` and inside `vue-property.d.ts`.